# How to Access Firebase Firestore Python Trigger Event Data?

Tags: python, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

Is this some sort of format that I'm not familiar with in Python? I'm wondering because I'm not sure if there's a better way to access these values.

*The documentation doesn't show clear information on how to access variables, and being a cloud service, the cycle in debugging this data is EXTREMELY slow - At least 4 minutes*

**On a Firestore Trigger**

```
def job_trigger(data, context):
    print(data["oldValue"])
```

The output is:

```
{"createTime": "2019-07-14T19:26:54.577250Z", 
"fields": {"0": {"integerValue": "0"}, "14": {"integerValue": "73"}, "2": {"integerValue": "17"}, "20": {"integerValue": "91"}, "30": {"integerValue": "150"}, "4": {"integerValue": "29"}, "5": {"integerValue": "30"}, "7": {"integerValue": "36"}}, 
"name": "projects/aerial-grid-233801/databases/(default)/documents/jobData/weWereYoung/overrides/indexOverrides", "updateTime": "2019-07-17T06:57:41.153135Z"}
```

Do I have to access data through `data["oldValue"]["fields"]["0"]`? Or something similar. This actually isn't working either...

I'm finding this format extremely hard to deal with and would've just converted my project to Javascript had I known? Unless I'm missing something about it.

Can I access these variables in an easier way?

Comment: Hi, if u are using firebase, i suggest you use pyrebase and their streamhandler method. I am on my phone now so im unable to link it, but im pretty sure thats what u are looking for.

Comment: Hi! I'm actually using the Cloud Firestore Triggers, so I shouldn't need to use PyCharm, although it may be a good resource to look at now... https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/calling/cloud-firestore?hl=en-GB